# How can I log into SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, macos, sqlplus

I am studying databases at the minute and I installed Oracle 19.3 so I can use SQLPlus on MacOS but I couldn't log in because the installation happened at Terminal so I couldn't see any usernames or passwords.

I tried all the default ones but none of them worked and I asked my teacher about it but I'm missing a service name that I'm supposed to know during installation. She couldn't help me.
I'm lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and check if you have ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID enviroment variables set. If so try issue the command:
sqlplus / as sysdba